# How to create new line in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello how can I divide it into 2 different lines? Then it's called inside of div in different class.

`this.setState({errorMessage:"First Line. Second Line"});`

Comment: @DennisVash Not sure if that's exactly what OP wanted! 

Comment: @MonteCristo Don't suggest that point.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<div>` or `<p>` tag with `<br />` tag. You can use any of the following:

```
this.setState({ errorMessage: <div>First Line.<br />Second Line</div> });
this.setState({ errorMessage: <p>First Line.<br />Second Line</p> });
```

A quick tip will be, don't use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml), which might get you into more troubles.

Comment: How else would you render it?

Comment: @MonteCristo I *just answered* how to render it. Just telling that there are more troubles in the other way.

Comment: ahh I see what you did there... I was thinking that it would be a html string. yeh make sense :)

Comment: @MonteCristo Oh, you mean this? **https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-glade-47p7m?file=/src/App.js**